# How to show div next to image icon with CSS and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with info where the last column has an icon that when mouse is over it show a `div` with info about that record, it looks like this

[ORIGINAL VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDpyK.png)

I would like to do that when mouse is over the blue icon display the `div` (rectangle with black background) next to the icon mouse is over, every icon show different info, this is my code for that

**CSS**

```
.info-extra {

     position: fixed;
     z-index: 999;
     background-color: black;
     color: white;
     width: 300px;
     height: 150px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px gray;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
echo '<td><img src="Images/iconos/fatcow/FatCow_Icons16x16/information.png" onmouseover="mostrarInfo('.$extra.')" onmouseout="ocultarInfo('.$extra.')"></td>';
echo '<div id="extra-'.$extra.'" class="info-extra" style="display: none;">
           <p>Hola</p>
      </div>';
```

This is the expected view

[EXPECTED VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/We65K.png)

it should be aligned next to the icon centered, how can achieve this? obviously it has to work in same way with every icon, I hope you can help me, thanks.

**Javascript**

```
function mostrarInfo(numero) {

   $('#extra-' + numero).show();
}


function ocultarInfo(numero) {

   $('#extra-' + numero).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$extra` in the `onmouseover` does not have quotes, so it is being passed into the function as a variable. Use escaped quotes for this (`\"`). Otherwise, the div displays when the image is hovered over. As for the centering the div, you can pass a height for each `<td>`, then set each div's position from the top as that.

```js
function mostrarInfo(numero,n) {
  $('#extra-' + numero).css('top',(200 + n)+"px");
   $('#extra-' + numero).show();
}


function ocultarInfo(numero) {

   $('#extra-' + numero).hide();
}
```

```css
.info-extra {
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 999;
     background-color: black;
     color: white;
     width: 100px;
     height: 150px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px gray;
     left: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>abcahtohaeth</td><td>defetathao3hg</td><td><img src="Images/iconos/fatcow/FatCow_Icons16x16/information.png" onmouseover="mostrarInfo('a',20)" onmouseout="ocultarInfo('a')"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abcahtohaeth</td><td>defetathao3hg</td><td><img src="Images/iconos/fatcow/FatCow_Icons16x16/information.png" onmouseover="mostrarInfo('a',40)" onmouseout="ocultarInfo('a')"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abcahtohaeth</td><td>defetathao3hg</td><td><img src="Images/iconos/fatcow/FatCow_Icons16x16/information.png" onmouseover="mostrarInfo('a',60)" onmouseout="ocultarInfo('a')"></td>
  </tr>
</table><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="extra-a" class="info-extra" style="display: none;">
           <p>Hola</p>
      </div>
```

Comment: But `$extra` is a number, I don't think that is related with I'm asking...in good way, I have no problem with my javascript code, I just wanted to show the div next to the icon, thank you anyways :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I updated my code with this and is far far away to be what I expected, but you gave me some ideas